# Moving from Web.Mail to Net.Mail, replacing MailMessage.Fields?

Tags: .net, vb.net, email

I'm trying to update some older software which uses the now-declared-obsolete **System.Web.Mail** classes. Unfortunately, I don't really know a heck of a lot about email, so I'm looking for advice.

Here is the fragment of code I'm looking at revising:

```
Dim myMessage As New Web.Mail.MailMessage
Dim cdoSendUsingPort As Integer = 2
Dim cdoNTLM As Integer = 2
myMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver", Options.SMTPServer)
myMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", 25)
myMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing", cdoSendUsingPort)
myMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", cdoNTLM)
```

From what I can tell, this should be configuring some kind of sending option. I can kind of work out what's going on, but I don't know how I should go about re-implementing it...

It's *looking* like the place to be putting this stuff is now in the **System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Credentials** class, but the information in there doesn't seem to bear any resemblance to what I have here.

I'm almost certain I'm making some obvious error, here, but I can't see it. Can someone tell me what I *should* be doing?

Comment: Just noticed the cdoNTLM, are you sending a username/password in the existing code?

Comment: cdoNTLM = 2, apparently. I can't see any evidence that a username is being sent. What's puzzling me is that the Credentials I'm able to send don't really line up well with those Fields added above, but I can't see anywhere else to do it.

Comment: Is this an exchange server you're sending mail to? If so which version?

Comment: Apparently it's Exchange 2010, SP1, according to my boss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what's actually going on here, and it looks like this function is never even used. The program does send mail, but it doesn't send it via this function. The whole program is a mess, pulled together from a pile of external libraries.

I've just commented out everything that was causing an error and made a note to make the attempt to rip out this entire library when I can find the time.

I would have closed this question, but it won't let me, and the mods didn't close it after I flagged it.

Leaving this as a non-answer to say that the matter is resolved, even if the problem was never solved...

Answer (score 3):

As you've noticed there's a few differences between `System.Web.Mail` and `System.Net.Mail`.

Here's a working example:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim myMessage As New MailMessage
    myMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress("bob@example.com", "Bob"))
    myMessage.From = _
     New MailAddress("noreply@mydomain.com", "MyDomain Senders Name")
    myMessage.Subject = "Test mail"
    myMessage.Body = "Hello world"

    Dim server As New SmtpClient
    server.Port = 25
    server.Host = "your server name"
    server.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    server.UseDefaultCredentials = True

    server.Send(myMessage)

  End Sub

End Module
```

There's an excellent resource called [System.Net.Mail - Oh My](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) which has great examples of how to use `System.Net.Mail`.

You can also configure the `SmtpClient` settings in your `web.config` or `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
      <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
          <network defaultCredentials="true" host="your server name"/>
        </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

In your code you'd just do this instead:

```
Dim server As New SmtpClient
server.Send(myMessage)
```

**Update:**

I just noticed that you're using NTLM authentication. Try one one of the following:

```
Dim server As New SmtpClient
server.Port = 25
server.Host = "your server name"
server.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

''// If no username/password being send then try this:
server.Credentials = _
    CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.GetCredential(_
        New Uri("smtp://yourserverfqname"), "NTLM")
''// or this
server.Credentials = _
    CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.GetCredential(_
        New Uri("smtp://yourserverfqname"), "NTLM")
server.Send(myMessage)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to my SystemNetMail.com website. Always glad people use the site.  --Dave

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.Mail is configured in the web.config/app.config of the application, see scott gu's post here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

There is also a C# guide on how to send mail, but that should be fairly easy to port to VB

**Edit:** VB end to end. http://forums.asp.net/t/971802.aspx

Comment: Well, yeah, that's the easy stuff. I don't want to send default credentials, though. At least, I do if .Credentials is the correct replacement for .Fields...

Answer (score 1):

As Beliskner mentioned, you can set most of the relevant properties in your web.config file.

You can also set them through your SmtpClient instance. However, if you can use just the .config file, this is a better place.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

You'll need that instance to call .Send() with your MailMessage anyway.